# How to reset jquery datepicker onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

My jquery date pickers work exactly as they should, however my issue is that if one of the datepickers is removed from the textbox then the value in the date calculated box (CalcDate1) should disappear. My code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker7').datepicker({
            showOnFocus: false,
            showTrigger: '#calImg',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            pickerClass: 'noPrevNext',
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) { $("#datepicker8").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate) },
            onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                $('#datepicker8').datepicker('option', "calculateWeek", min);
                datepicked();
            }
        });
        $('#datepicker8').datepicker({
            showOnFocus: false,
            showTrigger: '#calImg',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            pickerClass: 'noPrevNext',
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                $('#datepicker7').datepicker('option', "calculateWeek", max);
                datepicked();
            }
        });
    });


    var datepicked = function () {
        var from = $('#datepicker7');
        var to = $('#datepicker8');
        var nights = $('#CalcDate1');

        var startDate = from.datepicker('getDate');
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

        var endDate = to.datepicker('getDate')

        // Validate input
        if (endDate && startDate) {
            // Calculate days between dates
            var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);  // Start just after midnight
            endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);  // End just before midnight
            var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
            var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

            // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
            var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
            var days = days - (weeks * 2);

            // Handle special cases
            var startDay = startDate.getDay();
            var endDay = endDate.getDay();

            // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
            if (startDay - endDay > 1)
                var days = days - 2;

            // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
            if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
                var days = days - 1

            // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
            if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
                var days = days - 1

            nights.val(days);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I added the following two pieces of code to the their relative datepickers but they didn't work

```
keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
        $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
        $( "#datepicker8" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "today" );
    }
});

keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
            $.datepicker._clearDate(this);
            $( "#datepicker7" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "" );
        }
    });
```

My html helpers are

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateToAdvisors, "Date To Advisors", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateToAdvisors, new { @class = "datepicker7", id = "datepicker7" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateToAdvisors)
                                </div>
                            </div>

<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:75px">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReplyFormAdvisors, "Reply From Advisors", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReplyFormAdvisors, new { @class = "datepicker8", id = "datepicker8" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReplyFormAdvisors)
                                    </div>
                            </div> 

<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:175px">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CalcDate1, "Date Calculated", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CalcDate1)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CalcDate1)
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure `$( "#datepicker8" ).val("")` helps! try it though as you're not unbinding the DP.

Comment: @LShetty where would this be placed?

Comment: Replace `$.datepicker._clearDate(this);` with that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out but it didn't work. The line $( "#datepicker8" ).val("") makes one date disappear if the other date disappers but  the total still remains even after one of the dates has been removed. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I changed your code slightly to adapt it to mine, so that it now reads $("#CalcDate1").val(""); This does exactly what I need, thanks for your help in helping me achieve this